# usage of phrase "something that would have been at home on something"

Tags: phrase-usage

> “*I’ve watched a woman with skin pale as moonlight open her mouth, and open it, and open it, into a cavern set with rows of serrated teeth **that would have been at home** in a shark’s jaws*” - Excerpt From: John Langan. “The Fisherman.”

I tried using the phrase in a sentence.

> She had feet that would have been at home on a big foot.

Is this the right way? if possible please add a few examples.

Comment: You've used it more or less the right way. It's an ironic form, somewhat colourful. Ideally, you wouldn't wait for the second thing to say what's unique about the feet (their size). You would *first* qualify the feet, so we get the image: "She had oversized feet" and *then* make the joke about where they would belong: "that would have been at home on a yeti." Note that this is a rhetorical device, not strictly English grammar/usage.

Comment: A fine day, " he said, in a voice which might have been at home on the Shakespearean stage, and yet which, for all its resonance, struck a false note.

Answer (score 1):

Close.  The phrase is just another kind of simile, where a feature of one thing is compared with a similar feature of another thing, to create a picturesque image:

> Her many sharp teeth, set in serrated rows, were like shark's teeth.

To do this well you will want to create some kind of *expectation* that the comparison makes sense, otherwise it's a dull and lifeless picture:

> Her feet, massive and ungainly, were like Bigfoot's feet.
>   Her feet, massive and ungainly, **would have been at home** on a Bigfoot.

This would be correct ... but still not particularly *clever*.  Bigfoot literally has "big feet", yes?  So you're just saying one big-footed thing is like another big-footed thing.  Why not use something else with big feet:

> Her feet, massive and ungainly, would have been at home on an *elephant*.
>   Her feet, massive and ungainly, would have been at home on a *rhinoceros*.
>   Her feet, massive and ungainly, would have been at home *holding up a ten-story building*.

And so on.